# chroot SSH on debian 8

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, chroot

I would like to chroot my ssh connexion on my debian 8 server but I ahve a problem.

I found this tutorial https://www.howtoforge.com/chrooted-ssh-sftp-tutorial-debian-lenny but I have an error.

I sue this script:
http://www.fuschlberger.net/programs/ssh-scp-sftp-chroot-jail/make_chroot_jail.sh

he say:

```
usermod: user johnde is currently used by process 21730
Adding User rdata to jail
Copying necessary library-files to jail (may take some time)
cp: cannot stat '/lib/libnss_compat.so.2': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/lib/libnsl.so.1': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/lib/libnss_files.so.2': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/lib/libcap.so.1': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/lib/libnss_dns.so.2': No such file or directory
Copying files from /etc/pam.d/ to jail
Copying PAM-Modules to jail
cp: cannot stat '/lib/security': No such file or directory
```

Did i make something wrong ?

thanks.

Comment: You are attempting to copy files which don't exist.  If they are not crucial for the jail, maybe don't try to copy them, or just ignore the errors.  The comment just above the problematic section suggests that you may be able to use the script even if these don't exist.

Comment: Thanks for ur help, but after to follow the tutorial, i cannot login with ssh. break pipe. Dont understand

Answer (score 1):

The library file locations changed between Lenny (actually Squeeze) and Jessie.  Compare the path to `libnss_compat.so.2` in [squeeze](https://packages.debian.org/amd64/libc6/filelist) to the one in [jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libc6/filelist) and adapt the code accordingly.

Hard-coding paths in the script seems less than ideal, anyway; perhaps, the part of the code which figures out where to find libraries (the part with `ldd`) should perhaps remember where it found them, and attempt to copy the remaining libraries from the same location(s).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a patch file to fix make_chroot_jail.sh so it works with Debian 8.2 (aka Jessie) 32-bit.  In theory it should work with the amd64 version too as I looked up the new lib folder names for it too.  But I have not tested that.

http://www.jonmccain.net/downloads/make_chroot_jail_jessie.patch

use the command:

```
patch -i make_chroot_jail_jessie.patch -o make_chroot_jail_jessie.sh
```

to get the new script.

Comment: Thanks for the patch Jon. Works great!
In case anyone else is looking for it, the download links can be found at Jon's site: http://jonmccain.net/artchrootjailjessie.php